# Is it possible to extend jquery dialog with some properties similar to the browser alert object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, jquery-ui-dialog, alert

I want to use JQuery dialog from jqueryui.com, to pop certain async messages to the user.  The problem with the modal dialogs is that the user won't know about these unless he is on the particular tab of the browser.

The browser alert on the other hand shows up irrespective of whether the user is on the tab that originated the alert.  But the browser alert looks ugly and as far as I know it is not possible to apply css etc. on it.

Is there a way to show the modal dialog in a way that ensures that the user sees it even if he is not on the originating tab?  I have put together an example to illustrate the difference. Check it out at: http://jsfiddle.net/ywEDb/16/

Thanks,
Tabrez

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible but you can try to get focus on the active window where you are showing the dialog box.

Comment: Shankar - Thanks for the reply.  I tried setting the active window focus, but that does not work when there are multiple tabs on the browser.  I was not able to find any generic way to set the focus on a tab. Any suggestions?